# React hooks doesn't re render component when props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement counter of processed items and I'm using React hooks for this purpose.
My component uses variable "itemsProcessed" which is updating asynchronously in action and pushed to the Redux store by using dispatcher.

```
result = await reader.read();

      itemsProcessed += 1;
      dispatch({
        type: ITEMS_PINGING,
        payload: itemsProcessed,
      });
```

then in my component I'm using mapStateToProps

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      itemsProcessed: state.itemsProcessed,
    });
```

and useEffect hook to make component rerender my UI when itemsProcessed is changed

```
    const [pItems, setItemsProcessedCount] = useState('');
.
.
.

    useEffect(() => {
    setItemsProcessedCount(props.itemsProcessed);
  }, [props]);
```

and UI like this:

```
<div className={Styles.list}>
    {props.someCondition < 1 ? (
      <div>
        {pItems}...  //if I do this way {props.itemsProcessed} the same result (only three dots, without number of items processed)
      </div>
    ) : (
      _itemsGrid()
    )}
  </div>
```

The question is why I just see ... on the screen instead of:

1...

then

2...

then

3...

then

4...

and after all the items is processed I just see the list of all items.
When I'm trying to debug this case I see how the itemsProcessed is being changed and even see the numbers on the screen (like 2...) But it's only in debug mode. When I close debug console and refresh page I just see ... and nothing else until the list of items is shown.
So, React doesn't rerender my pItems after it's changed.

P.S. my reducer looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  itemsProcessed: 0,
};

const itemsPinging = (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    itemsProcessed: action.payload,
  });
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case constants.ITEMS_PINGING:
      return itemsPinging(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you using a hook at all? Surely you can use `pItems` straight from props?

Comment: ...and you don't need to wrap a call to the update function from `useState` inside `useEffect` either. What's your actual question?

Comment: pItems is a state variable which is allowed in React 16.8 and I'm not using {props.pItems} I'm using {pItems}

Comment: @Dmitry But you you are initialising your state with what is in `props.itemsProcessed` and always update it according to that value. There is no point in using state if it is always equal to `itemsProcessed`. Your component does re-render anyways if any prop changes.

Comment: I agree, I can change this one <div>{pItems}...</div>  with this one  <div>{props.itemsProcessed}</div>,  but the result will be the same

Comment: If it is the same and doesn't work, then there's an issue with how you are using reducer.

Comment: Can you add the code to codesandbox to see in detail where it is going wrong?

Comment: I've added my reducer in P.S.

Comment: I've noticed that I forgot to add my itemsProcessed to the initialState. When I added it, I just see 0... and that's it

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

1. There's no need to use state for pItems. If the value of pItems gets updated, the component will re-render and you'll have the new values.
2. You cannot do this `{pItems}` if `pItems` is an array or object. Do `{JSON.stringify(pItems}` and see it shows up (just for testing purposes).

To render a list you should do something like this:

```
{ pItems.map(item => <div> item </div>) }
```

Comment: An array is actually valid as a child but the items must be valid children too. In this case the items are strings so this is technically valid. `pItems.map(...)` also returns an array.

Comment: pItems is just a number which I want to show before three dots

Comment: Then just use `props.itemsProcessed` instead of `pItems`

Answer (score 0):

Also use the new redux hooks if you are using hooks inside your react app

useDispatch hook
useSelector hook

refer redux new Docs.
This will provide a better code formatting.